# `AbortError` within IndexedDB `upgradeneeded` event

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, indexeddb

In the following code, Firefox adds an `AbortError` to console while Chrome does not.

```
var bugDB = 'test1';
var delReq = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(bugDB);
delReq.onsuccess = function () {
    var req = indexedDB.open(bugDB);
    req.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
        console.log('upgrade');
        req.result.close();
        console.log('finish closing');
    };
};
```

Although this error doesn't prevent execution of "finish closing", it does cause problems in Mocha/Chai testing for Firefox (though no such error occurs if `req.results.close()` is called within a `req.onsuccess` handler. Is this a bug in Firefox? If the `AbortError` is being propagated somewhere (by design?), how can one successfully trap it (`e.target.result.onabort` is not working)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is per spec:

https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#opening

"steps for opening a database" 8.2: if the connection was closed after upgrade but before success - which would happen when `close()` is called because the close does not actually happen until the upgrade transaction completes - then the open request fails with `AbortError` as you're seeing.

The behavior is the same in Chrome and Firefox; Chrome just doesn't log the error by default. If you add:

```
req.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(req.error.name, req.error.message); 
};
```

... you'll see it in Chrome too.

Comment: That difference between the logging was the gotcha for me, thanks...So I can prevent the subsequent aborting with `preventDefault`. Btw, speaking of `preventDefault`, I think 3.1.11, under example 4, the second example, has `transaction.onerror` before a call to `createObjectStore` whereas I think it should instead be `request.onerror`.

Comment: It appears from my testing (at least when working within Promises) that certain IndexedDB errors can be caught with try-catch (and be safely supplied to a Promise `reject`) and others can only be caught with `preventDefault` within `onerror` (otherwise, the Promise `reject` (or `resolve`) will never be reached). If this is the case, is there a way to distinguish which types of actions will see which type of these two error types?

Comment: `transaction.onerror` is fine. Error events bubble up from the request to the transaction to the database. As written, that example makes any ConstraintError from `add()` not abort the transaction.

Comment: Synchronous errors detectable at the point of call (i.e. you provided an invalid key, a non-cloneable value, the transaction has already finished, the transaction is inactive, the store or index is deleted, the cursor is already advancing, etc) throw. Failures from the actual operation (i.e. constraint error, a request processed after an abort, etc) fire events.

The list of synchronous failures (and what is thrown) is detailed in the spec for every method.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten one could obtain `transaction` via `e.target.transaction` or `req.transaction`. Your high-level explanation on synchronous errors vs. event firing helped frame it very much better for me, as I was not grasping it from a reading of the spec. I was conflating throwing and error event firing. Thank you.